# vue / nuxt - import CSS from API and insert it in component

Tags: css, vue.js

I want to insert into component inline css like

```
<div id="slide1" :style="item.css" v-html="item.html" />
```

Where my item.css contains string with many css definitions e.g.

```
#slide1 {} #slide1 p {} #slide1 h2 {} @media(...) { #slide {} }  ....
```

What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: The `style` property of an HTML element will contain CSS properties, not class definitions. You should insert that content either using a link to the resource to load it as CSS, ore add it to a `<style>...</style>` tag

Comment: Just to follow up on my comment above, Vue will ignore (with a warning) any `<style>...</style>` block from your template.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are doing here is not loading styles, you are loading a full `css` set of rules. The `style` property of an HTML element will only let you add `css` properties, not blocks of rules like `#slide1 {...}`.

If you want to load the rules for a singular component remotely, you will want to do use a scoped style block for your component (assuming you are using [single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)), like so:

```
<template>
...
</template>

<style scoped>
@import url("link-to-your-remote-styles");
</style>
```

What we're doing above is:

- making sure that the styles loaded in this component will not bleed out of its scope by using the `scoped` attribute of the `<style>` tag;
- loading the styles using the @import [rule from CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_import_rule.asp)

[Here's a link to a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/remote-style-scoped-21s1i) where I load tailwind just for the scope of one component.

Comment: i know how attach css from remote link.But what i want to do is download css as string from API  and insert it.
Somthing like 

`<style scoped>
this.cssString
</style>

<script>
.... 
this.cssString = reponseFromApi.css
</script>`